# Is it possible to search on a DC.js graph from a search bar?

Tags: data-visualization, dc.js, searchbar

I'm working with [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) in order to make a dashboard.

I have a Piechart which countain much information and it's not good for the visualization.

**What I have ?**

[image]

**What I Want ?**

I'm just asking if there is a way to search on this `Piechart` like having a **search-bar** and posting some text which will serve to get these entries ...

Thank you in advance;

Comment: How can I achieve the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the input filter from this pull request for dc.js - it does a partial text match and filters based on the results.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/936

It still needs work to merge but it is functional. You ought to be able to drop in the code, either by editing dc.js or by adding filter-input.js to your page.